# how to print a function in Symbol form without re-writing?

Tags: python, printing, sympy

Let's say we got this function:

```
def f(x,y):
    return 2*x*y
```

and also define

```
y=1
x= sympy.Symbol'x'
```

Would there be any way to print

```
print(f(y,x))
2*1*x
```

other than `print(2+'*x')`... etc?

Comment: @ncica you mean return f"2*x*{y}" ;) but I doubt that's what OP wants

Comment: it's the same, just different syntax ;) @SV-97

Comment: @ncica I know, but it's the newer more efficient Syntax :D

Comment: Yeah, this is a simple form of a function. It could be like 10 series of a function. So I would like a more compact solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the function with your symbol should actually evaluate to 2*x which you can simply print out.

REPL session:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x = sympy.symbols("x")
>>> x
x
>>> def f(x, y):
...     return 2*x*y
... 
>>> f(x, 1)
2*x
>>> print(f(x, 1))
2*x
```

Comment: I get the error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'"  for the code:
`def f(xx,yy):
    return 2*x*y,
yy=1.0
xx=sympy.Symbol('x'),
print(f(xx,yy))`

Comment: @Bill Honestly: please format your code - It works fine for me - see edit of my answer

Comment: If this `def f(xx,yy): return 2*x*y` is your complete function: you don't have x and y  declared in scope of the function and aren't using the args you've defined. Maybe you have x or y declared externally as function and int? would explain your error message

Comment: To add onto this(though it's more of a headsup and only semi-related): you can declare a sympy Symbol as real (`sp.Symbol("x", real=True)`). I often encountered errors with unresolved operations in formulas when omitting this.